# How to have my recorded macro move to the next person in my list

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list that has names and I have recorded a macro to help me copy, paste, format and move to next names in list. It is working, however something crucial is missing because the macro does not keep the previously recorded data, and it does not move to next names in list.

I ran the macro of different rows and tried recording the macro again but it is not working as expected

```
Sub Accrual()
'
' Accrual Macro
'

'
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$G$1007").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= _
        "doe, john"
    Range("A2").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet4").Select
    Range("A2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("Sheet3").Select
    Range("B2:C2").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet4").Select
    Range("C2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("E2").Select
    Sheets("Sheet3").Select
    Range("F2:F6").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet4").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=True
    Range("A3").Select
End Sub
```

I would expect my recorded macro to go down my list of names and copy, paste, and format all the names in the list and keep all the data

Comment: Have a search on here for looping through data with vba

Comment: Why have you removed the code? It was good to see it in the question...

Comment: Here is the code https://i.stack.imgur.com/8rfJL.png